# Change DIV background when INPUT filed has data. How?

Tags: html

I have an input field inside a div, and I would like the div background to change when the input field has data typed inside.

How is this done?

Comment: Also, try to add some information about the constraints you're working under. Are you confined to a certain version of CSS? Do you use a special javascript library, or no javascript libraries at all?

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use jQuery to solve this problem. Load jQuery in your `<head>`tag, and attach to the keypress event on your input field, by adding this javascript snippet in a script tag below the inclusion of jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myInput").keypress(function() {
        if($("#myInput").val().length > 0) $("#myDiv").css("background-color", "red");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div input').keypress(function() {
    $(this).val().length > 0) {
        $(this).parent().css("background-color","red");
    } else {
        $(this).parent().css("background-color","none"); 
    }
});
```

If you want to be kind to your web designers and make friends with them, you could also dynamically apply and remove a class attribute:

```
$('div input').keypress(function() {
    $(this).val().length > 0) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("background");
    } else {
        $(this).parent().removeClass("background");
    }
});
```

Then your designers can adjust the look and feel in the CSS file, using the CSS "background" class hook, without having to worry about messing up your beautiful JavaScript masterpiece. It also gives them greater flexibility to make changes, without putting all the presentation logic in your business logic code.

```
/* Example CSS rule */
input.background {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px 4px red;
}
```